# Selenium / Python TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to print and/or write to file text inside a span tag from the following HTML. Only want it to `find_element` once, not `find_elements` since there's only one instance:

```
<div>
  <span class="test">2</span>
</div>
```

Below is the python code I'm using that is generating the "'WebElement' object is not iterable" error.

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div")

for numberText in test:
numberTexts = numberText.find_element_by_class_name("test")

print(numberTexts.txt)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting a single element (first one) by:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div")
```

which is obviously not iterable.

For multiple elements i.e. to get an iterable, use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div")
```

Note the `s` after `element`.

Also check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: Thank you! Adding "elements" to the first line of code did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

single element will not be iterable.  Try find_elements_by_xpath (pluralize element).

If there is only one instance, then simply use it without the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

the error is pretty clear... 
the return value of `find_element_by_xpath` is a `WebElement`.  You can't iterate a `WebElement`...

you have several other mistakes in your example code.  You could rewrite the entire block of code as:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("test")
print(element.text)
```